# react-native : cant add props to component

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

im working on simple program. I have List.js and Detail.js and i want to get List.js state in Detail.js using Props but not working (props returns nothing). I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324617/react-native-doesnt-update-child-component-props) but still not working. This is what i did so far  :

List.js :

```
import {Detail} from './Detail';
.
.
.
.
GetItem (nama,id) {
  this.setState({id: id});
  return this.props.navigation.navigate('detail');
}
.
.
.
.
render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (

      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
      <View><TextInput style={{height: 40,width: 300, marginTop:10}}
      onChangeText={this.onKeyChanges.bind(this)}
      />
      </View>
        <View><ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer}
          onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, rowData.nama,rowData.id)} >{rowData.nama}</Text>}
        />
        </View>
      <Detail data={this.state.id}/>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Detail.js

```
export class Detail extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: props.data
    }
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        nextState.id = nextProps.data;
    }

  render() {
    return <Text>{this.state.id}</Text>;
  }
}
```

the `<Text>{this.state.id}</Text>;` shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this,

```
GetItem (nama,id) {
  this.setState({id: id});
  return this.props.navigation.navigate('detail');
}
```

to this

```
// setState is asynchronous
GetItem (nama,id) {
  this.setState({id: id}, () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('detail');
  });
}
```

And you need to get new prop on Details component and update the state. There is a really good answer for [Why you shouldn't modify state directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40309023/2315280)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ id: nextProps.data });
}
```

Comment: thanks that is a good answer, but the `<Text>{this.state.id}</Text>` still shows nothing, seems like the props from List.js is not passed to Detail component. because when i try `this.setState({ id: "Test" });` the state did not changed @bennygenel

Comment: It can be a visual problem. Please do `console.log(nextProps.id)` in `componentWillReceiveProps` and see if you can see the right id.

Comment: the `console.log(nextProps.id)` prints undefined, seems the problem is on List.js when passing props to Detail, but i dont know why @bennygenel

Comment: Can you try changing `onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, rowData.nama,rowData.id)}` to `onPress={(event) => this.GetItem(rowData.nama, rowData.id)}`

Comment: it still undefined @bennygenel :'(

Comment: can you update your question with the last version of it please

Comment: i got it sir, i changing the nextProps.id to nextprops.data, thank you!! @bennygenel

Comment: I was just writing that